# What's the difference between these three forms of syntax for calling a method?

Tags: c++

The following both call the function `T::f` on object `t`.

```
1. t.f();
2. t.T::f();
3. (t.*&T::f)();
```

I've seen the second one used where the other was not. What is the difference between these two and in what situation should one be preferred?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I forgot about the second one `t.T::f()`. I added that one in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `t.f()` and `(t.*&T::f)()` are semantically identical and are the "normal" way to call a member functions. The call `t.T::f()` calls `T::f()` even if `f()` is an overridden virtual function.

The expression `(t.*&T::f)()` calls a member function by obtaining a pointer to a member function. The only potential effect that this expression could have is that it might inhibit inlining the function for some compilers. Using a variable obtained from `&T::f` to call a member function would be a customization point but directly calling the function is merely obfuscation and potentially a pessimization (if the compiler isn't capable to do sufficient const propagation to detect that the address can't change).

What I could *imagine* is that someone *tried* to inhibit a virtual function call on `t`. Of course, this doesn't work this way because the pointer to member will still call the correct virtual function. To inhibit virtual dispatch you'd use `t.T::f()`.

You should prefer `t.f()` over `(t.*&T::f)()`. If you want to inhibit virtual dispatch you'd use `t.T::f()` otherwise you'd use `t.f()`. The primary use for inhibiting virtual dispatch is to call the base class version of a function from within an overriding function. Otherwise it is rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the regular one, that's the one you should prefer. The second one takes a *member function pointer* to `f`, dereferences it for `t`, and then calls it.

If there is an actual benefit in that extra trip I am not aware of it. This is the member version of `*&f()` when calling a *free function*.

The one that you added later on, `t.T::f()`, is *statically dispatched* so that the `f` of `T` is called even if it were virtual and `t` were a derived class of `T` with its own implementation. It effectively inhibits the virtual call mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is pointless, it's just obfuscated code. No it doesn't disable virtual dispatch nor inlining. They both do the exact same thing, in each and every case.